# How to include a variable when including a page (PHP)

Tags: php

I have developed a shopping cart that submits the order total amount as a hidden variable across pages as the user selects options throughout the checkout process.  On the last page, where the user inputs his/her credit card information, I require that the user check a Terms of Use box.  If the user does not select the box, an error message is displayed along with the last checkout page beneath it.

Unfortunately, if I use include(page.php) to display the checkout page, the order amount is $0.00 because it is not including the order total that I have been passing across pages.  Is there a way to get the value of that variable to show up on the page?  Or is there a better way to display the error message than to use echo for the message and then include to display the page beneath it?  I need to be able to point out the error and still have the order total display on the page.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use $_SESSION

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to pass such an important variable via user submitted data; doing this may cause users to pay less than what they're supposed to pay.

A better approach is to store this value inside a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), i.e.

```
session_start();
// update the total
$_SESSION['total'] = 123;
```

Then, in the checkout page:

```
session_start();
echo "Total: ", $_SESSION['total'];
```

Sessions are perpetuated with session cookies, comprising a session identifier; at each request the cookie is sent along with the request, so that the system can locate the actual data on disc (or another storage medium).

Note that `session_start()` must be run *before* any output is sent to the browser.

Comment: Don't forget to encrypt your values!

Comment: @Darick Don't forget to get dedicated hosting ;-)